# wxGCDC UTF8 Problems

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am having problems with `DrawText` when using UTF8 encoded text. The problem mostly happens with emojis such as  which corresponds to `"\xF0\x9F\x98\x81"`

```
void CFrm::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxAutoBufferedPaintDC pdc(this);
    pdc.Clear();

    if (m_Antialiasing)
    {
        wxGCDC gcdc(pdc); //works only with some fonts
        Draw(&gcdc);
    }
    else
    {
        Draw(&pdc); //works all the time
    }
}
```

Elsewhere to draw the text I use `dc->DrawText(wxString::FromUTF8(Label), TextLoc);` where the variable `Label` is a *std::string*. If `wxGCDC` is not used the emojis are shown correctly. I also experimented with a few non-English words (Turkish, Chinese ...) and they seemed to work correctly; however emojis are shown as squares. On the other hand things work when the following fonts are selected:

1. Segoe UI Emoji
2. Segoe UI Symbol
3. DejaVu Sans
4. EmojiOne Color

Any ideas appreciated (Platform Windows 11, wxWidgets 3.2, Visual Studio 2022)

Comment: Not all MS-Windows fonts include all characters.  You can use the Character Map application to see what characters are available in a font.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the font replacement character shown instead of the expected emoji or something else?

Comment: @VZ. Yes, there is a font replacement character (generally a rectangle) shown instead of the emoji when `wxGCDC` is used. When `wxAutoBufferedPaintDC` is used, emojis are shown regardless of the selected font.

Comment: It seems very weird that the use of `wxAutoBufferedPaintDC` would change anything here. If you can reproduce this problem in a simple self-contained example, please open an issue for this.

Comment: @VZ. That's what I was wondering as well, why should it show when `wxAutoBufferedPaintDC` is used but why not when `wxGCDC` is used. Maybe it is something to do with GDI / GDI+?